# How to set default value for Dry::Validation.Params scheme?

Tags: ruby, validation, dry-rb

I have next scheme

```
Dry::Validation.Params do
  optional(:per_page).filled(:int?, lteq?: 1000)
  optional(:page).filled(:int?)
end
```

If I pass empty hash for validation I get empty output but I want to set default values for my data.

I tried `Dry::Types.default` but it does not add default values in output. That's what I tried.

```
Dry::Validation.Params do
  optional(:per_page).filled(Dry::Types['strict.integer'].default(10), lteq?: 1000)
  optional(:page).filled(:int?)
end
```

Is it possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 2):

The `Dry::Validation` has not this purpose.

I recommend you to use [dry-initializer](http://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-initializer/) on your params before pass it to the validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```rb
optional(:per_page).filled(Types::Integer.constructor { _1 || 10 })
```

Or define your own fallback strategy as here https://github.com/dry-rb/dry-types/pull/410

```rb
optional(:per_page).filled(Types::Integer.constructor { |input, type| type.(input) { 10 } })
```